# path function for URL throwing error when we want to capture an integer or slug paramter

Tags: django, django-views

I am a beginner in django 2.2.4. I was trying to the following the urls.py file.

```
from firstapp import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', views.index),
    path('articles/2003/', views.index),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.index),
]
```

I see that the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/2003/ executes the views.index. However, when I run the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/2005/ ,there is an error.

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/2005/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'
```

Why is this not working?

As above.It was expected this ur would be matched by the line

```
path('articles/<int:year>/', views.index).
```

Comment: please show `views.index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `views.index` should take a parameter called year, something like:

```
def index(request, year):
    ...
```

Right now it must be only

```
def index(request):
    ....
```

And `/articles/2003/` is working because you have an explicit path set for in your url conf:

```
    path('articles/2003/', views.index), # matches articles/2003/, calls views.index(request) with no year param
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.index), # matches articles/2005/, calls views.index(request, year=2005), throws error
```

Remove the explicit path for `articles/2003/`, add the `year` param to `views.index` and then things should work.